# How to run protractor tests with maven on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, protractor

I am new to protractor (for angularjs ui app) and I want to run my protractor tests with maven in Jenkins for CI. I searched for maven plug-ins which does this magic but couldn't find one. Please can anyone one help me with this.

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use Maven with jenkins? Otherwise you may simply wrap execution command inside a bat/shell file and directly run from Jenkins as step.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Protractor via Maven. I have not done it but it appears that it does exist. My personal opinion is to not add another layer of complexity and just use node in your Jenkins CI.

A quick search to maven and protractor, I came across this [stackoverflow for maven + protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723648/running-protractor-tests-as-part-of-the-maven-build-process) with the corresponding [maven plugin project on github](https://github.com/greengerong/maven-ng-protractor).